# I need to do qunit for my project, I cannot pass the values to my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

```
var subType = document.getElementById("subscriptiontype").value;
var subName = document.getElementById("subscriptionname").value;
```

How can i  pass the `subType` and `subName` from another javascript code manually.

Comment: You can assign in global varible

Comment: I need to call from another .js file

Answer (score 0):

Yes can access global varibles in different js.you have to declare at top of your code.   OR you can directly access this values document.getElementById("subscriptiontype").value any where in any js.

Comment: I agree Deepak, if i run the qunit i am getting this error document.getElementById(...) is null.

Comment: if you using jquery then put your code in $().ready(function(){..});. OR elaborate your question so can understand what is the actual problem?

Comment: test("EmailSubscription", function() {

     document.getElementById('subscriptiontype').value = 3;

     equal(validate(), true, "success!!!");

});